# Can't open a deeplink in foreground with React Native for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, deep-linking

We are using firebase deeplinks in a react native application built for both iOS and Android.

Example deeplink: https://monedacacao.page.link/RifKomEk3bhNM9CW9?d=1

**Expected behavior:**

1. User scans a QR Code that contains a deeplink in `QRScannerScreen`
2. `onSuccess (e)` is triggered and the link is opened using `Linking.openUr()`
3. In `ReduxNavigation` `Firebase.links().onLink()` is triggered and redirects the user to `SendDestinataryScreen`

**Actual behavior**

In Android this works as intended, but on iOS `Linking.openURL(e.data)` opens a browser with the Firebase fallback link instead of triggering the `Firebase.links.onLin()` action.

If the link is clicked from outside the application it behaves as intended. So this problem only occurs when opening the link from inside the application.

**QRScannerScreen.js**

```
  ...
  onSuccess (e) {
    Linking
      .openURL(e.data)
      .catch(err => console.error('An error occured', err))
  }
  ...
```

**ReduxNavigation.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { BackHandler, Platform } from 'react-native'
import { addNavigationHelpers, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'
import { createReduxBoundAddListener } from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'
import AppNavigation from './AppNavigation'

class ReduxNavigation extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    // handle deeplinking
    firebase.links().onLink((url) => {
      console.log('URL', url)
      if (this.props.token) {
        this.props.dispatch(NavigationActions.push({
          routeName: 'SendDestinataryScreen',
          params: { link: url }
        }))
      } else {
        this.props.dispatch(NavigationActions.push({
          routeName: 'LoginScreen'
        }))
      }
    })
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') return
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
      const { dispatch, nav } = this.props
      // change to whatever is your first screen, otherwise unpredictable results may occur
      if (nav.routes.length === 1 && (nav.routes[0].routeName === 'LaunchScreen')) {
        return false
      }
      // if (shouldCloseApp(nav)) return false
      dispatch({ type: 'Navigation/BACK' })
      return true
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') return
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress')
  }

  render () {
    return <AppNavigation navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch: this.props.dispatch, state: this.props.nav, addListener: createReduxBoundAddListener('root') })} />
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ nav: state.nav, token: state.authentication.token })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxNavigation)
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: Sorry, intended to use the `deep-linking` tag.